# plot stringgrid values on Tchart

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

I'm trying to plot a graph with some values on my `Stringgrid`. it has 140x140 rowxCol, numbers only. The `Tchart` should display on the X-axis the cell coordinates, in the y-axis the values.

I'm using this code:

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  Count: Integer;
begin
  with StringGrid1 do
  begin
    for Count := 0 to RowCount-1 do
    begin
      Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(StrToFloat(Cells[0, Count]), 
                             StrToFloat(Cells[1, Count]), '', clTeeColor);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But I keep getting this error: `'' is not a floating point value.`

Comment: We can't see your string grid's data, but you're obviously converting an empty string to a floating point value. Check the value in your string grid on the coordinates you're passing to the `Cells` property. Note, that the indexes passed to the `Cells` are 0 based and includes the fixed cells.

Comment: Why didn't you fill the chart from the source you filled the grid? Controls are for showing data not storing them. Keep the data in an array of extended and fill the grid and chart from this array.

Comment: the values are imported from a Excel spreadsheet, sorry for not telling that, but I think it doesn't matter as long as the values are in the string.

Comment: Try `ShowMessage(StringGrid1.Cells[0, 0]);` and `ShowMessage(StringGrid1.Cells[1, 0]);` before the loop, and please tell us what do you see.

Comment: You need to learn how to use the excellent debugger that you have. Had you used it you would have seen that you are passing empty strings to StrToFloat. Please do learn to use your tools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're converting an empty string to a floating point value, what is naturally impossible. My guess is that you're passing wrong coordinates to the [`Cells`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid.Cells) property. Note that they're both 0 based and that they include also the fixed portion of the string grid. Here's the [`Cells`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid.Cells) coordinates printout:

[image]

Comment: Demonstrative! Much better than trying to explain what *fixed* row, col is with words..

Comment: So how do I start looping from the [1,1]?

Comment: That's what you should know. You have filled that string grid with data. It's just my guess, that you've started your loop from coordinates, where's the fixed col and/or row, but that empty string, which fails the conversion may be wherever inside the grid.